# Function on distributions with a given property

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Does there exist any function that inputs two distributions and outputs a third distribution where the output distribution is guaranteed to have density on the supports of both input distributions?

Note that the two distributions could be supported on arbitrary spaces, eg on two non-parallel non-overlapping lines in space.

Thoughts on how to construct such a function or how to prove it does not exist would be useful.

Comment: If your question is meaningful (*density* is a rather special word), then a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) may do this

Comment: I expect you want the "new" distribution to have some properties...otherwise you could just output the first of the two inputs, say.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Lulu The first of them, can have zero density on the support of second one. But I am looking for non-zero density on both supports.

Comment: So, take half of each.  Meaning, for each observation, flip a fair coin and go with first or second input accordingly.  You can use a weighted coin if you prefer.

Comment: @Lulu That would a mixture. As Henry above also suggests.

Comment: @Henry, Thanks! where in my question seems potentially wrong?

Comment: Well, suppose one of your distributions was supported on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^2$ and the other on $\mathbb{R} \times {0}$ each with a density which made sense for itself.  The mixture would have the combined support as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but would it have a density?

Comment: @Henry I thought the density exists in a mixture and is the linear combination of original densities, but I guess your question suggests it does not exist. Why is that?What is the root of the problem?

Comment: My issue is the concept of a density on a combination of arbitrary spaces